# Loadbalance two ngnix docker containers with HAproxy

Tags: docker, dns, haproxy

I have installed HAproxy on two vagrant VM (both debian buster) and has setup keepalived to manage a single VIP. I am running two nginx docker containers on each machine. When I use the IP address for the 'backend' everything works as it should.
When I use the hostname of the container HAproxy says

```
Nov 16 21:12:05 buster haproxy[24426]: [ALERT] 320/211205 (24426) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:48] : 'server server1' : could not resolve address 'nginx1'.
Nov 16 21:12:05 buster haproxy[24426]: [ALERT] 320/211205 (24426) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:49] : 'server server2' : could not resolve address 'nginx2'.
```

### Docker setup

```
docker network create web-net
docker run --name nginx1 --hostname nginx1 --network web-net -d nginxdemos/hello
docker run --name nginx2 --hostname nginx2 --network web-net -d nginxdemos/hello
```

### HAproxy configuration

```
global
    ...

defaults
    ...

resolvers docker
    nameserver dns 127.0.0.11:53

frontend http-in
    bind 192.168.100.200:80    # VIP
    default_backend servers

backend servers
    balance roundrobin
    server server1 nginx1:80 check resolvers docker resolve-prefer ipv4
    server server2 nginx2:80 check resolvers docker resolve-prefer ipv4
```

Comment: How are you launching HAProxy; is it also in a container on the same Docker network?

Comment: @DavidMaze No, I have installed it on the VM. I am running the nginx docker containers inside the VM. HAproxy is run a daemon on the VM. I restart the daemon every-time I change the HAproxy configuration.

Comment: It has to be in a container and on the same Docker-internal network to resolve the Docker-internal hostnames.  If it's not in a container, you need to use a `docker run -p` published port, with the IP address of the VM that's running it (or `localhost` if you know it's the same VM).

Comment: @DavidMaze I have the VM's in a bridge network setup. (i.e, it is exposed to host network). VIP is working on 80 port and the nginx test containers are also on port 80 but on different subnet (172.18.0.1/16). Since the nginx containers already expose port 80 by default. I can access the webpage served by the nginx and load-balance between the containers. When I change it to the hostname on the container. It fails. I looked inside the container and the dns inside the resolv.conf is pointing to the 127.0.0.11 as well. I tried the docker0 interface ip as well, but no luck.